# How to translate show engine INNODB status?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am transitioning from a programmer into DB and looking at this result looks like hieroglyphics to me. Can someone help me understand and read this result?

I executed the following code:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

and I got this result (please open it in pastebin)

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-8NEXz9xTt1dDG_w80vhes0Czg38V5c/view?usp=sharing
```

Thank you so much for your replies and I hope to learn so much from this community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  It's hieroglyphics.  I avoid it.

When it shows "the last deadlock", just look at the two queries -- that's the most important bit of info.  Go find those queries in your code; see if you can speed them up and/or keep them out of each other's hair.

Your particular example ... Are you missing some `COMMITs`?  What is the value of `max_connections`; sounds like it is ludicrously high.  How fast are you repeating `SHOW ENGINE STATUS;`?  Maybe so fast that it is stumbling over itself?

I see these:

```
SELECT  ID, groupid, FIELDTYPE, FIELD, FIELDID, OLDVALUE, OLDSTRING,
        NEWVALUE, NEWSTRING
    FROM  changeitem
    WHERE  (groupid IN (2148520, 2148521, 2148954, 2148955, 2148957,
                        2337772, 2694891) 
           )
```

Is there an index starting with `groupid` in `changeitem`?

```
UPDATE  userhistoryitem SET entitytype='Searcher', entityid='status',
        USERNAME='armine', lastviewed=1527555906745, data=null
    WHERE  ID=385440
```

Is `ID` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `userhistoryitem`?

Comment: That is the result of a Jira that is having a high CPU load. I am currently new in the job and learning what might be causing it. My max connection is set to 300.

Comment: I recommend looking in the SlowLog.  More details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: When I look at the slow query logs, the latest entry was dated 2 days ago prior to this slowness I am encountering. What are your suggestion when deadlock happen to the sql?

Comment: @MiksMeister - Lower `long_query_time` to catch more queries.  The default of 10 seconds is almost useless.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for all those info.

Comment: Hi Rick, On your question, groupid and FIELD are only index in the changeitem table and ID is the PRIMARY KEY of userhistoryitem